# does luaExpat provide apis to find tag or attributes?

Tags: xml, lua

I'm using LuaExpat to do some xml parsing.
I wonder whether it provides apis to do "getTag", "getAttribute", so I have to write that by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to pass callback functions to LuaExpat which enables you to extract values, print stuff out or whatever your use case is. Below is a short example that prints out the `id` attribute of an element.

```
p = lxp.new({ StartElement = function(parser, elementName, attributes)
                           print(attributes.id)
                         end
})
p:parse('<xml id="123"></xml>') --> 123
```

I recommend checking out http://www.keplerproject.org/luaexpat/manual.html for more instructions.